# Finding the previous update version

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using Tortoise svn. But my Eclipse workspace is not merged with the svn folder. I copy the source from svn folder and work on a separate folder.

I updated my source several days ago but didn't commit. Up to now other people have committed their source to svn. Today I accidentally updated from svn without putting my modifications in to the svn folder. Now what I want is to update the svn source in my hand to the revision that I updated on previous day.

Is this possible? I know I can do this if I could find the revision number that I updated on previous day. But, how do I find it?

Version info: TortoiseSVN 1.6.16, Build 21511 - 64 Bit

Comment: Still no answer...? Can't believe ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got an answer. When we access the log by going `TortoiseSVN -> show log`, `Tortoise SVN` does not show the information about our previous updates(it only shows information about commits). However we can find its `log` file (*logfile.txt*) in `\AppData\Roaming\TortoiseSVN` folder (*Windows 7*). It contains details about both updates and commits. So we can easily find any updated version number. 

Note:- You can set the maximum number of lines the log file maintains by going 
`TortoiseSVN -> Settings -> Saved Data -> Max. lines in action log`

Thanks for everyone who replied.

Answer (score 1):

This is only possible by hard. If I understood you correct, you copied the sources from

```
/subversion
```

to

```
/workspace
```

without the .svn subfolders. This is where subversion and tortoise saves the current revision number. By updateing /subversion you changed this old revision number you initialy worked with to a new one. There is no history which saves which was locally the one before.

You can however diff every revision step with your sources and find this number by hard. The better question is: Why should you do that? It's much better to work with [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/), that is a subversion plugin for eclipse. Checkout from eclipse and work within eclipse without tortoise. If you want to use tortoise anyway watch for the same subversion version to get no conflicts...

After checkout with subclipse in /workspace/newCheckout you can diff `newCheckout` and `subversion` folders and copy your changes again.

Comment: Hey, what is revising a question? Where does one see this in the gui?

Answer (score 0):

`TortoiseSVN -> show log` - this shows list revisions.

Same, you can build revision graph - `TortoiseSVN -> Revision graph`

Comment: Yes but the log shows only the commits done to the svn?(Am I correct?) So how can I find the revision number that I updated before? (Not commited)

Comment: Sorry, i'm not understand, what do you do. You doing that: update, resolve conflicts, merge your branch ?

Comment: Simply, **1.** I don't use the svn folder as workspace. **2.** I want to find the revision number to which I updated before.